# Open source drone technologies

Tags: aircraft-design, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

What is the best place to understand the details of drones?  Preferably something open source.  Books would also be helpful.

Comment: What aspect of drones are you trying to understand? At the moment, your question is essentially, "Drones: tell me all about them!", which is far too broad.

Comment: OP: Asking what the best of anything is pretty much ensures your question will be put on hold.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple of open source UAV projects:

- [Paparazzi](http://wiki.paparazziuav.org/wiki/Main_Page) is a complete system of open source hardware and software for Unmanned Aircraft Systems, including [autopilots](http://wiki.paparazziuav.org/wiki/Autopilots) and a [ground control and planning station](http://wiki.paparazziuav.org/wiki/GCS). All of the hardware plans and software source code you need to make a drone from scratch are available on [github](https://github.com/paparazzi/paparazzi-hardware). But not everyone has the equipment to make a printed circuit board at home.
- [Open pilot](http://www.openpilot.org/) is an autopilot for UAVs. They also sell hardware if I remember properly, which might make it a bit easier if you're just starting.

If you just want a simple introduction to flying drones, [DIY drones](http://diydrones.com/profiles/blogs/a-newbies-guide-to-uavs) has a quick guide to the basics.